# why am I getting my last part of my unicode string eaten?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am trying to generate ascii to javascript unicode , and I could generate it , but after checking some aspects . I notice my program is eating the last part of the string. how can I fix this?

```
import binascii

content = 'string\n'

first_byte = ""
second_byte = ""
shellcode = ""
flag = 0
for b in content:
    if flag == 0:
        shellcode += "%u"
        first_byte = binascii.hexlify(b)
        flag += 1
    else:
        second_byte = binascii.hexlify(b)
        shellcode += second_byte
        shellcode += first_byte
        flag = 0

print shellcode
```

my output from the script

```
%u6c62%u6361%u6c6b%u6965%u7574%u
```

desired one, but in general whatever string

```
%u6c62%u6361%u6c6b%u6965%u7574%u0a73
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the variable `flag` to split your input into two parts. The even characters are saved in `first_byte`, and when you get the odd character you save both into `shellcode`. At the end of the loop you have a character in `first_byte` that you haven't output yet, if the number of characters is even.

Comment: what would it be the best for adding the correct output to it?

Comment: @alfredorivas I don't know how you derived your correct output so I can't say. Besides it would deprive you of a learning exercise.

Answer (score 0):

See [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57814416/4518341) for the explanation of the problem. As for how to fix it, you could iterate over the string in two-byte chunks using one of the examples from here: [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/312443/4518341)

```
import binascii

content = 'string\n'

def chunks(sequence, n):
    """
    Yield successive n-sized chunks from the sequence.

    Modified from https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/4518341
    """
    for i in xrange(0, len(sequence), n):
        yield sequence[i:i+n]

shellcode = ''
for t in chunks(content, 2):
    shellcode += "%u"
    if len(t) > 1:
        shellcode += binascii.hexlify(t[1])
    shellcode += binascii.hexlify(t[0])

print shellcode
```

Output:

```
%u7473%u6972%u676e%u0a
```